# How Do You Ignore A Comma

Tags: java

I was wondering how to get the code to ignore commas between the day and the year.

Ex) I want java to separate "January 15, 1983" (with no line separation) into "January" as a string(month), 15 as an integer (day), and 1983 as an integer(year).

I tried using the following code I thought of, but when I ran it, it couldn't ignore the comma.

```
String month;
int day, year;
Scanner keyboardIn = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a date\n(Month Day, Year) or (XX/XX/XXXX):");
month = keyboardIn.next();
day = keyboardIn.nextInt();
year = keyboardIn.nextInt();
System.out.println(month + " " + day + " " + year);
```

Comment: See [`String`: `split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/

Comment: Split with regex, perhaps `String regex = ",?\\s+|/";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remore the `","` from the line and scan again with default delimiter:

```
Scanner keyboardIn = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a date\n(Month Day, Year) or (XX/XX/XXXX):");

String date = keyboardIn.nextLine().replaceAll(",", "");

Scanner dateScanner = new Scanner(date);

String month = dateScanner.next();
int day = dateScanner.nextInt();
int year = dateScanner.nextInt();

System.out.println(month + " " + day + " " + year);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String formattedInput = rawInput.replaceAll( ",", "")` and then parse the `formattedInput` string

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) on string like this

```
String date = "January 15, 1983 ";
        String[] chunks = date.split(" ");
        System.out.println(chunks[0]);
        System.out.println(chunks[1].substring(0, chunks[1].length() - 1));
        System.out.println(chunks[2]);
```

output

```
January
15
1983
```

Answer (score 0):

The default whitespace delimiter used by a scanner is as recognized by Character.isWhitespace.

You can read that [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Maybe you can approach the problem in a different way. Read the complete line and break the sting into tokens. Something like this:

```
String line = sc.nextLine();
String tokens = line.split(",");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the commas (with `replaceAll()`) and then split the string:

```
String str = "January 15, 1983";
String[] arr = str.replaceAll(",","").split("[ ,]");
for(String s : arr) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output:

```
January
15
1983
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] line = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
String month = line[0];
String day = line[1].replaceAll(",","");
String year = line[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

## Date-Time Object

As a more general solution, convert the string to a date-time object. Then extract the information you need.

First thought might be java.util.Date. Ill-advised as that class and it's partner java.util.Calendar are notoriously troublesome. Those in the know use either the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the java.time package in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310). Both offer a [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class to represent date-only values without any day-of-time or time zone.

## Joda-Time

```
String input =  "January 15, 1983";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "L-" ).withLocale( Locale.US );
LocalDate localDate = formatter.parseLocalDate( input );
int month = localDate.getMonthOfYear();
int year = localDate.getYear();
int dayOfMonth = localDate.getDayOfMonth();
```